# Matrix Multiplication in Java Without Using Imports

Tags: java, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to make a method that reads input from 2 files, each containing a matrix. The objective is to check if they can be multiplied (if the length of the rows of one is the same as the length of the columns in the other) then create a product matrix of the two inputted matrices. Here is what I have so far. It doesn't work, and I wasn't expecting it to. I just want to get some help on the logic part of the method.

```
public class MatrixOps {

    public static double[][] multiply(double[][] matrix1, double[][] matrix2) {
        int matrix1Cols = matrix1.length;
        int matrix1Rows = matrix1[0].length;
        int matrix2Cols = matrix2.length;
        int matrix2Rows = matrix2[0].length;
        double[][] productMatrix = new double[0][0];

        if (matrix1Rows == matrix2Cols) {
            productMatrix = new double[matrix1Cols][matrix2Rows];
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix1Cols; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix1Rows; j++) {
                    productMatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[j][i];
                    for (int k = 0; k < matrix2Rows; k++) {
                        productMatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (matrix1Cols == matrix2Rows) {
            productMatrix = new double[matrix2Cols][matrix1Rows];
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix2Rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix1Cols; j++) {
                    productMatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[j][i];
                    for (int k = 0; k < matrix2Rows; k++) {
                        productMatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return productMatrix;
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how to get it to work?

Comment: Why is your productMatrix initialized to  `new double[0][0];`? If I'm correct A ( dimension: n x m) multiplied by B (dimension: m x p) produces AB (dimension: n x p)

Comment: I did that just to initialize the array. The method has to work for different inputs. So if the first matrix that is entered has the same amount of rows as the second matrix has columns, then the product matrix will be different dimensions than if the first array that is entered has the same amount of columns as the second matrix has rows.

Comment: Just a comment on style: it seems that your `multiply(a,b)` could return `a*b` or `b*a` depending on the dimensions. I would suggest not doing that and consistently making it `a*b`, otherwise that would make the use of `multiply()` confusing. Think of it this way: for someone using the method, what would it return if both `a` and `b` were n x n matrices? By definition, `multiply(a,b)` should only return `a*b` and throw some error if the dimensions don't match.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not necessary to do product matrix on both loops:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < matrix1Cols; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < matrix1Rows; j++) {
         productMatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[j][i];
     for (int k = 0; k < matrix2Rows; k++) {
         productMatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[j][k];
     }
 }
```

This is sufficient:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix1Cols; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix1Rows; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < matrix2Rows; k++) {
            productMatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[j][k];
       }
   }
}
```

Also if you are changing the order of the matrix multiplications, then it must be reflected on your operation (seems you are just doing copy paste)

so on the second part:

```
if (matrix1Cols == matrix2Rows) {
```

The matrix multiplication has to change from:

```
productMatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[j][k];
```

to:

```
productMatrix[i][j] += matrix2[i][j] * matrix1[j][k];
```